# AVL-Tree - хранение

Tags: алгоритм, файлы, c++

Я хочу в каком-то формате хранить AVL-дерево в файле. Как это можно сделать?

При этом чтобы он имел читабельный вид, но и чтобы можно было при написанном варианте (который ты сам отредактируешь), потом его собрать в дерево.

Пока и не знаю, что можно сделать. Если есть какие-нибудь предложения, с радостью их выслушаю!
  Спасибо заранее!

Comment: [xml](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)?

Comment: ну можно хранить в виде `"id_cell"` + `"id_parent"` при загрузке сортировать по паренту(`<`) и строить дерево...
 
но тогда теряется смысл AVL-Tree...

либо хранить просто как список(без id) и тогда дерево строить с нуля